# How do I make an SVGSVGElement from paper.js downloadable?

Tags: javascript, svg, export, paperjs

I'm using [paper.js](http://paperjs.org) and I want to make a button to download a snapshot of the canvas at any point. Paper.js has an `exportSVG` function that will return either an [SVGSVGElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement) or a string with SVG code. How can I make a button that will simply download this into a `screenshot.svg` file for the user?

In other words, How can I cause a browser to create a file to download from a string or `SVGSVGElement`?

Comment: Why is this marked down and marked for closing?

Comment: See http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/06/Don-t-Build-Blobs-Construct-Them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this with [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/):

```
var svg = paper.project.exportSVG({asString: true});
var blob = new Blob([svg], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, 'image.svg');
```